# Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined magento 2

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I'm getting an error in the console and it says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined.

The file it relates to is `requirejs-config.js:1149` but I have no idea what this relates to or how to fix it. Any ideas?

The code in question is:

```
})(require);
require.config(config);
})();
```

Comment: You post anly part of code. It's not valid java script code.

Answer (score 11):

You probably have a `requirejs-config.js` file somewhere in your codebase that is empty. Magento includes every `requirejs-config.js` file it finds, but it does expect it to contain a config object.

In terminal, in your Magento root, run;

`find . -type f -iname requirejs-config.js | xargs ls -1lathr`

Look for files that are 0 bytes. Either remove those files or place an empty config object in it;

`var config = {};`

That should fix it.

Comment: I commented the complete content of a requirejs-config.js file. Has same effect as an empty file... Your hint helped me out, thx!

Comment: Right on the money!

Comment: I own you a beer! :D